# WordPress database error Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction for query. . .'_transient_astra-theme-cron-test-ok'

Tags: sql, database, wordpress, datastax-astra

I'm encountering a database deadlock error.

[29-Sep-2023 09:41:45 UTC] WordPress database error Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction for query DELETE FROM `wp_options` WHERE `option_name` = '_transient_astra-theme-cron-test-ok' made by require('wp-blog-header.php'), wp, WP->main, do_action_ref_array('wp'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, Astra_Theme_Background_Updater->install_actions, Astra_Theme_Background_Updater->test_cron, get_transient, delete_option

I've attempted to repair the 'wp_options' table by SQL command "REPAIR TABLE wp_option;", but it hasn't resolved the issue. Do you have any insights into what might be causing this?